# Acumatica- reference fields Data

Tags: acumatica

I have a Form detail page (Order) where the form area has the data that is referential data like InventoryItem_Descr

and Graph for Order page has main view query  -

`public PXSelectJoin<Order,
          LeftJoin<InventoryItem, On<Order.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>>> QCOrders;`

Code used on other page to open Order page -

`OrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<OrderEntry>();
      graph.Orders.Current = null;
      graph.Orders.Current = (PXResult<Order, InventoryItem>)graph.QCOrders.Search<Order.OrderCD>(OrderNumber);
      if(graph.QCOrders.Current != null) {
        throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graph, "Order Detail", true) { Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.InlineWindow };

      }`

**Issue -**
  when the page is opened from other page by PXRedirectException,the referncial fields are blank 
While if it is refreshed after it opened or opened from side map it works as expected.

what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

On the aspx page for Order, make sure that the pxdatasource.PageLoadBehavior is 'PopulateSavedValues'